# How to edit local meteor packages and push it to git

Tags: git, meteor

I'm using `lepozepo:cloudinary` package

I created `packages` folder in my app and I cloned the repo and made changes to according to my requirements and then I pushed my meteor app code to git,

but the local package code is not pushing to the server, how to use the code that I changed, without publishing to the atmosphere?

**EDIT**

For now I'm doing like below

1. Removed .git folder in the package and
2. removed git link,package name and version in pacakges.js
3. Added the package with the name of the folder ex:

   `packages/cloudinary`
   then

   `meteor add cloudinary`

and then when I push it to the git ,my changes are also pushed to the repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the package is currently a submodule, as it's been cloned into an existing repo, so commits on the main app don't include changes on the package.

Assuming the package is working as you expect, you can tell git to bring it back into the main module (and thus commit changes to it) by following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule/16162000#16162000).

Answer (score 2):

Could you just copy it in a lib folder in your app directly and not declare it as a package ?